# Cross-browser background - gradient plus image

Tags: css, background, gradient

i have tried to make gradient with image as a background, but is does not working in any browsers excluding web-kit based. Can you help me with that issue.

```
background: url("../images/pattern.png"), -moz-radial-gradient(60% 120%, circle, #dfd5a8 0%, #2f71a9 110%);
background: url("../images/pattern.png"), -webkit-radial-gradient(60% 120%, circle, #dfd5a8 0%, #2f71a9 110%);
background: url("../images/pattern.png"), -o-radial-gradient(60% 120%, circle, #dfd5a8 0%, #2f71a9 110%);
background: url("../images/pattern.png"), -ms-radial-gradient(60% 120%, circle, #dfd5a8 0%, #2f71a9 110%);
background: url("../images/pattern.png"), radial-gradient(60% 120%, circle, #dfd5a8 0%, #2f71a9 110%);
```

Thank you very much.
PS: i tried to apply for myself http://modernizr.com, but i do not sure that it is nice way to connect plugin for that.. Possible is it possible to make it just using pure css.. i hope so.

Answer (score 0):

Use a colorspace with an alphachannel like `rgba` or `hsla` to be able to make the gradient semi transparent and use the correct order and it will work:

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/nUC83/1/)

```
background:radial-gradient(60% 120%, circle, rgba(223, 213, 168, .75)   0%,
                                             rgba( 47, 113, 169, .75) 110%),
           url("http://placekitten.com/g/200/300");
```

Comment: Is does not working in Opera and IE.. In other working as well, but my version is working in other browsers as well too..

Comment: radial gradient is not supported in IE below version 10... Opera should support it.

Comment: Yes.. I thought so, that Opera should support it. but i checked it on 12.10 version, OS- windows xp and it does not work..